# Adding Google accounts with third-party authentication in iOS Settings

Tags: javascript, ios, authentication, google-oauth

We're a university using Google Apps for Education. Google defers to our Central Authentication Service (CAS) server when people log in over the web. (i.e., if John Smith goes to gmail.com and enters his @example.edu email address in the login page, Google sends him to our site to enter his username and password before letting him in.)

We changed our website template this morning and we found that when people tried to set up their accounts in iOS' Settings app (e.g. Settings -> Mail, Contacts, and Calendars -> Add account -> Google), they would enter their email address and be sent to our login page, like usual, but as soon as the page finished loading, the authentication screen would go away and they'd be bumped back to the screen with all of the account type options (iCloud, Exchange, Google, etc) - *before* they had a chance to put in their username and password.

I disabled most of the Javascript running on the page. (I left Typekit, Modernizr, and Google Analytics, and commented out jQuery and all of our custom code.) That seems to have fixed the problem, which I'm guessing was some sort of event being triggered that made iOS think the flow was complete. Does anyone know anything about how iOS determines that the authentication flow is complete? Any ideas what to Google for? I don't even know what this would be called, so any tips would be helpful.